# jupyder notebook: OSError: [Errno 2] "dot" not found in path

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, caffe2

I use jupyder notebook:

```
from IPython import display
graph = net_drawer.GetPydotGraph(train_model.net.Proto().op, 'mnist', rankdir='LR')
#graph.write_png("lenet.png")
display.Image(graph.create_png(), width=800)
```

and I encounter this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-95f1d8e2feb8> in <module>()
      2 graph = net_drawer.GetPydotGraph(train_model.net.Proto().op, 'mnist', rankdir='LR')
      3 #graph.write_png("lenet.png")
----> 4 display.Image(graph.create_png(), width=800)

/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydot.pyc in new_method(f, prog, encoding)
   1660                 """Refer to docstring of method `create`."""
   1661                 return self.create(
-> 1662                     format=f, prog=prog, encoding=encoding)
   1663             name = 'create_{fmt}'.format(fmt=frmt)
   1664             self.__setattr__(name, new_method)

/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydot.pyc in create(self, prog, format, encoding)
   1865                 args[1] = '"{prog}" not found in path.'.format(
   1866                     prog=prog)
-> 1867                 raise OSError(*args)
   1868             else:
   1869                 raise

OSError: [Errno 2] "dot" not found in path.
```

I can run the codes in terminal and pycharm successfully, but fail in jupyder notebook. 
could you please help me? thanks!
Besides,I have installed dot successfully such as:

```
sudo apt-get insall graphviz
pip install pydot
```

Comment: What is your machine?

Comment: it is ubuntu16.

Answer (score 0):

*brew install graphviz* worked for me.